# how to turn a formatted string using list unpacking to f-strings?

Tags: python, f-string

I want to turn my strings to f-strings, and I found a string like this:

```
print('{} : {}'.format(*[time.asctime(time.localtime(t)) for t in (time.time(), old_time)]))
```

How can I turn it to a nice fstring?

Now I'm using a lambda and calling it in both `{}`

```
print(f'{my_lambda(time.time()} : {my_lambda(old_time}'
```

But I still search for a way to unpack and distribute to both `{}` in the string

Comment: If you ask me, that's a bad use case for an f-string.  Why not just keep the `.format()` version?

Comment: @Alfe I think f-strings are more understandable, and using the lambda here, IMO, simplifies things, though, the functionality of unpacking a list in fstrings still intrigues me - even its for a bad practice...

Comment: Whether f-strings are more understandable or the `%`-variants or the `{}` notation of `.format` is a matter of endless debate.  I think it depends on the use case which is easier to read.  `"I have found %(found)s but I wanted to find %(expected)s while scanning through %(baseset)s." % dict(found=..., expected=..., baseset=...)` is very easy to read and understand IMHO.  But for smaller things like `f"The file {given_file_name} wasn't readable, trying {default_file_name} instead."` the f-strings make perfect sense.  In general:  The more complex the expression the less readable is an f-string.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
my_l = [time.asctime(time.localtime(t)) for t in (time.time(), old_time)]

f"{' : '.join(my_l)}"
```

if you do not want to add any extra message is kind of useless since you can use :

```
' : '.join(my_l)
```

also, you can use:

```
print(*my_l, sep=' : ')
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be to put the result of your computation into a list and using this for the printing:

```
times = [ time.asctime(time.localtime(t))
          for t in (time.time(), old_time) ]
print(f"{time[0]} : {time[1]}")
```

or, more speaking:

```
now, then = [ time.asctime(time.localtime(t))
              for t in (time.time(), old_time) ]
print(f"{now} : {then}")
```

This way you avoid code doubling (one code for both values) and even have speaking names in the f-string.